Properties of ethyl acetate as a solvent
I found that the ethyl acetate is a volatile organic solvent. But I also know that the ethyl acetate is a polar molecule. I thought that only nonpolar molecule can be a strong organic solvent. How can this problem be solved?

Typically chemists think of a solvent as a liquid. Every solvent can dissolve something, but not everything.

What parameter defines your solvent strength scale? I suspect you are mixing up solvent strength based on polarity $\varepsilon$ in the context of RP- and NP-HPLC. Also, you might want to correct the title as it poses a different question from the text body.

There is a wide polarity scale of organic solvents from alkanes on one side and methanol, dimethylsulfoxide and N,N-dimethylformamide on the other side.
Each solvent is "the strongest" in dissolving things with polarity similar to its own, interacting in the way the solvent molecule interacts. Nucleophilic solvents are good in dissolving electrophilic solutes and vice versa.
For very different solutes, the solvent is "weak". Methanol is "very weak" in dissolving non-polar substances and n-hexane is "very weak" in dissolving very polar substances.
The  above is modern formulation of the old rule invented by medieval alchemists:
"Similia similibus solvuntur."

See also solvent relative permitivity data as the measure of solvent polarity (Wikipedia.org - Relative permittivity)
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Solvent Formula} & \textbf{Solvent Name} & \textbf{Relative Permittivity} & \textbf{Temperature} \\
\hline
\text{C}_6\text{H}_6 & \text{benzene} & 2.3 & 298\ \text{K}\ (25^\circ \text{C}) \\
\text{Et}_2\text{O} & \text{diethyl ether} & 4.3 & 293\ \text{K}\ (20^\circ \text{C}) \\
(\text{CH}_2)_4\text{O} & \text{tetrahydrofuran (THF)} & 7.6 & 298\ \text{K}\ (25^\circ \text{C}) \\
\text{CH}_2\text{Cl}_2 & \text{dichloromethane} & 9.1 & 293\ \text{K}\ (20^\circ \text{C}) \\
\text{NH}_3(\text{liq}) & \text{liquid ammonia} & 17 & 273\ \text{K}\ (0^\circ \text{C}) \\
\text{C}_2\text{H}_5\text{OH} & \text{ethanol} & 24.3 & 298\ \text{K}\ (25^\circ \text{C}) \\
\text{CH}_3\text{OH} & \text{methanol} & 32.7 & 298\ \text{K}\ (25^\circ \text{C}) \\
\text{CH}_3\text{NO}_2 & \text{nitromethane} & 35.9 & 303\ \text{K}\ (30^\circ \text{C}) \\
\text{HCONMe}_2 & \text{dimethyl formamide (DMF)} & 36.7 & 298\ \text{K}\ (25^\circ \text{C}) \\
\text{CH}_3\text{CN} & \text{acetonitrile} & 37.5 & 293\ \text{K}\ (20^\circ \text{C}) \\
\text{H}_2\text{O} & \text{water} & 78.4 & 298\ \text{K}\ (25^\circ \text{C}) \\
\text{HCONH}_2 & \text{formamide} & 109 & 293\ \text{K}\ (20^\circ \text{C}) \\
\hline
\end{array}

Thank you for the detailed answer. So the point is that there are varying degrees of  polarity among organic solvents. Does this means that some organic sovents can be hydrophilic as long as they have polarity?

Yes, you have got that right. Some are very polar.
